# GPS systems for bikes

Tags: gps

I have never seen a GPS system available for when you buy your bike I'm wondering if the technologies out there for the bikes I know the technology is small and if its not available how do I get a patent

Comment: Many years ago I had a handlebar mount for a Garmin hiking-style GPS.  Now everyone (or near enough) who wants GPS on a bike will just use a smartphone.suitably mounted.  It's not like you'd want to have something permanently attached to the bike anyway -- theft.

Comment: How to get a patent is clearly out of scope for this site.

Comment: They use a small system on all the pro tour bikes.  I am pretty sure someone has several patents.

Comment: Algorithm for Patents.
come up with an invention, Repeat (keep quite about it, hand a fortune over to a patent attorney) forever

Comment: Clarify please - do you mean a GPS tracking system for your bike so you can find it?  Or a GPS tracking system to tell you where you are while riding?   Both exist, so you're not likely to patent the concept.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, plenty of manufacturers make GPS units for bikes. Some models to look out for if you want to research their capabilities include Garmin, Polar, Powertap, Lezyne and Mio. Depending on the model, these allow for recording of routes while you ride, or pre-loading routes for guidance.

Additionally, apps are available to use a smart-phone in this way.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the OP is asking about GPS embedded in the bike rather than buying a bike computer.  Similar to how Trek have integrated speed/cadence with duotrap.